# Read text file python Numpy

Tags: python

I have a txt file that has xyz coordinates extracted from Kinect. The xyz coordinates is separated by the commas and there is 12 columns. There is around 1200 rows as every movement I make in front of kinect 30 frames are added in one second.

[image]

Comment: So... where's your question mark? Any specific problem?

Comment: I have to read the data and extract the xyz coordinate and calculate the euclidean distance, angles etc. To start off, I need to read the file but i could not figure out. I can read the file and print the data as above but i have no clue how to get only xyz from certain column and how to calculate.

Thanks much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Is your doubt on what you should use to load it?

If so, to load directly into numpy you can use numpy.loadtxt (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

If you want a structure that will allow more flexible access and manipulation of the data, you should use pandas.read_table (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html).

After manipulation you can easily convert the pandas structure into numpy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of how you can read each line of your file and process its data.

**This code will:**

1. `open` file
2. `read` lines
3. `split` each line at space
4. `print` a few infos from each line
5. `for` each element that came after the first split, `split` it again at `,`

**Code:**

```
#create empty list to store results
rows = []

#open file
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    #read each line of file and store it in rows list
    rows = f.readlines()

#for each element in my list, do something
for row in rows:

    #split row in each space, so each column will become an element item and attribute it to data
    data = row.split()

    #print all data content
    print(data)

    #print only third element in data list
    print(data[3])

    #split column content at ,
    print(data[3].split(',')
```

Now you can access every item in each column. You just have to play a little with your data and understand how to properly access it.

But you should consider using the tools provided by Filipe Aleixo in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43071997/3846228), this way you'll be able to better manipulate the data.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! Just a hint: before asking your next question, you should read this post: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I will, it was my first time sorry.